# How to write such an initialiser in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, initialization

Please take a look at this piece of `Objective-C` code:

```
- (instancetype)initWithNothing
{
    self = [super init];

     if (self)
    {
       // do something that i wish
       // to do only here
       // not in usual init method
    }

    return self;
}
```

I use this method if I don't want use usual `init` method. Actually it is one more `init` that takes no parameters. How do I write such an initialiser in `Swift`?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html ?

Comment: Trivial code translation question.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha Code translation questions are off topic. What have you tried? Where is your problem?

Comment: @Sulthan are you kidding? What one can try here? What else can you suggest here for trying except googling? What would you try? Where is my problem? I don't know how to write such an initialiser in Swift. I don't know if it is even possible. It is written in my question

Comment: @Sulthan Not as trivial as you think.  Check my answer.

Comment: @robmayoff I consider it trivial. It helps to consider the solution in other languages, e.g. Java. Using initializers/constructors to solve such a problem is the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

In Swift, initializers are not normal functions.  They are declared with the `init` keyword and called using the class name (or by calling a variable that contains a class).  They are not declared using the `func` keyword, and have no name that is visible in the language.

Instead, write an initializer that takes a dummy argument to distinguish it from the normal initializer:

```
class MyObject: NSObject {

    init(nothing: AnyObject?) {
        super.init()
        // whatever
    }

    class func test() {
        let object = MyObject(nothing: nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class func createInstanceWithNothing() -> Self{
  return Self() 
}
```

where Self is the name of your class
and Self() is one of your init functions